# Number of solutions for a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> There are $n$ linearly independent solutions for a $n$th degree differential equation (if the equation has a solution).

Could someone explain if the above is true, and if so could someone give me the intuition behind why it's true?

From a linear algebra perspective it's relatively obvious - $n$ vectors are required to span $\mathbb{R}^n$. I was hoping for an explanation independent of linear algebra though.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for **homogeneous linear** equations (on an interval where the coefficients are continuous).  The basic idea is this: consider initial conditions at some given point $t_0$ in the interval.  For every vector $(x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb R^n$, there is a unique solution $y(t)$ to your 
differential equation with $y(t_0) = x_0,\; y'(t_0) = x_1, \; y^{(n-1)}(t_0) = x_{n-1}$, and every solution corresponds to some such initial condition at $t_0$.  Now if $y_0, \ldots, y_{n-1}$ are the solutions corresponding to initial conditions $(1,0,\ldots, 0)$, $(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, ..., $(0,\ldots, 0, 1)$,
for any $x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ we can get a solution 
$y(t) = x_0 y_0(t) + \ldots + x_{n-1} y_{n-1}(t)$ that satisfies
the initial condition associated with $(x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1})$.
That is, every solution is a linear combination of $y_0, \ldots, y_{n-1}$.
Moreover, it's easy to see that $y_0, \ldots, y_{n-1}$ are 
linearly independent.